MediaPipe hand detection works with direct camera access but fails with camera permission button implementation
I have two different implementations of a hand gesture detection system using MediaPipe, where one works perfectly and the other doesn't.
Working Implementation:
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np  # Added numpy import
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

class FingerCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mp_hands.Hands(
            max_num_hands=2,
            min_detection_confidence=0.5,
            min_tracking_confidence=0.5
        )
        self.mp_draw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        
    def count_fingers(self, hand_landmarks, handedness):
        tip_ids = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
        fingers = []
        
        # Thumb - different logic for left and right hands
        if handedness.classification[0].label == 'Right':
            if hand_landmarks.landmark[tip_ids[0]].x < hand_landmarks.landmark[tip_ids[0] - 1].x:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
        else:  # Left hand
            if hand_landmarks.landmark[tip_ids[0]].x > hand_landmarks.landmark[tip_ids[0] - 1].x:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
            
        # Other fingers - same for both hands
        for id in range(1, 5):
            if hand_landmarks.landmark[tip_ids[id]].y < hand_landmarks.landmark[tip_ids[id] - 2].y:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
                
        return fingers.count(1)

    def process_frame(self, frame):
        image = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.hands.process(image_rgb)
        
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for idx, (hand_landmarks, handedness) in enumerate(zip(results.multi_hand_landmarks, results.multi_handedness)):
                self.mp_draw.draw_landmarks(
                    image, 
                    hand_landmarks, 
                    self.mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                    self.mp_draw.DrawingSpec(color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2),
                    self.mp_draw.DrawingSpec(color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
                )
                
                # Count fingers with handedness information
                finger_count = self.count_fingers(hand_landmarks, handedness)
                
                # Position text based on hand
                text_x = 50 if handedness.classification[0].label == 'Left' else image.shape[1] - 250
                cv2.putText(
                    image, 
                    f'{handedness.classification[0].label}: {finger_count}', 
                    (text_x, 50), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                    1, 
                    (255, 255, 255), 
                    3
                )
                cv2.putText(
                    image, 
                    f'{handedness.classification[0].label}: {finger_count}', 
                    (text_x, 50), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                    1, 
                    (0, 0, 255), 
                    2
                )
                
                # Update total count
                cv2.putText(
                    image, 
                    f'Total Fingers: {sum(1 for hand in results.multi_hand_landmarks for _ in range(self.count_fingers(hand, results.multi_handedness[results.multi_hand_landmarks.index(hand)])))}', 
                    (image.shape[1]//2 - 100, 100), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                    1, 
                    (255, 255, 255), 
                    3
                )
                cv2.putText(
                    image, 
                    f'Total Fingers: {sum(1 for hand in results.multi_hand_landmarks for _ in range(self.count_fingers(hand, results.multi_handedness[results.multi_hand_landmarks.index(hand)])))}', 
                    (image.shape[1]//2 - 100, 100), 
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                    1, 
                    (0, 0, 255), 
                    2
                )
        
        return image

counter = FingerCounter()

def get_camera():
    # Try different camera indices
    for index in range(10):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
        if cap.isOpened():
            return cap
    return None

camera = get_camera()
if camera is None:
    print("No camera found!")

def generate_frames():
    while True:
        if camera is None:
            # Create a black frame with error message if no camera
            frame = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            cv2.putText(frame, "No camera found!", (200, 240),
                       cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            processed_frame = counter.process_frame(frame)
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', processed_frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), 
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)


index.html:



<!-- templates/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Finger Counter Web App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 800px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .video-container {
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
            background-color: #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #video_feed {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #2C3E50;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .status {
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hand Gesture Finger Counter</h1>
        <div class="video-container">
            <img id="video_feed" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" alt="Video feed">
        </div>
        <div class="status">
            Show your hand to the camera to count fingers
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



Issue Description:

The first implementation (shown above) works perfectly both locally and in production
It accurately detects hands and counts fingers for both left and right hands
The second implementation (i have added a github repo link for the second implementation), with camera permission button:
Successfully starts the camera when clicked
Shows video feed correctly
But MediaPipe hand detection fails to initialize/work


Second Implementation Github Repo
Log file while deploying it on render (the github one)

It would make more sense to include the code with the problem in your question. Currently, your question consists of a lot of code that works as intended, the description of a problem "MediaPipe hand detection fails to initialize/work" and a lot of context - to solve the question, or for anyone to benefit from it later, only the GitHub link is useful. It would also be helpful to know what you tried. Did you try cutting away most of the code that you think is irrelevant to the problem? Did you make any progress in trying to pin down what part of the code appears to be at fault?

[mre] required. -- these questions keep getting asked.

see honestly I have tried like multiple things, my first implementation is simple and works perfectly, now the second implementation is where I wanna convert this to a web app and by doing so, it fails badly everytime. I have no idea what exactly what im doing wrong

Please add more information like web browser console log, network protocol, backend logging protocol etc.

I have added the picture of the log file at the end as well, while I will was deploying on Render, it gave me this error. you can see my already deployed web app, only the camera works nut the hand detection does not.
here is the link of the web app : https://finger-counter-app.onrender.com/
